# Nifi putHiveStreaming Failed to connect to metastore uri

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, kylo

I'm facing issues with putHiveStreaming Processor as it is not connecting to hive metastore. I am using kylo-cloudera-sandbox-0.9.1, please help me on this as I'm not able to figure out the issue. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Sound as if your thrift server may not be running on the sandbox.  Start with a simple port test to see if it us up and running and then proceed from there.

```
 telnet localhost 9083
 lsof -i :9083
```

Comment: Thrift server is running on port 9083, Please find the lsof output              
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java             8920 hive  618u  IPv4 121273      0t0  TCP *:emc-pp-mgmtsvc (LISTEN)

Comment: I haven't done bucketing for my hive table after doing that I'm able to solve my issue.